# Book/webtoon about a boy with lightning(?) powers who was sent to army(?) school to practice

Tags: story-identification, books, powers, webcomics

I am looking for a book or the webtoon that was based on that book. I lost my webtoon account and I can't find the title.

As I remember, it was about a boy with superpowers (probably lightning) that was sent to army(?) school to practice. His nemesis was a slick Malfoy-like boy with white hair. It was also tagged as BL, but I didn't make it to that point of the story. A boy was mentored by some general.

I know that the book was published in English and then someone created a webtoon based on it.

Answer (score 5):

This is [The Fever King](https://m.webtoons.com/en/super-hero/the-fever-king/list?title_no=1659):

> The sole survivor of a magical plague, Noam Álvaro is accepted into an academy where he will be expected to defend Carolinia, the nation that persecuted his family. Noam decides to use everything he learns to destroy Carolinia . . . that is until he becomes distracted by a mysterious and powerful classmate who warns him that nothing is as it seems. (Based on the YA novel by Victoria Lee.)

His lightning powers (technopathy) are introduced in [Ep. 3](https://m.webtoons.com/en/super-hero/the-fever-king/ep-3/viewer?title_no=1659&episode_no=3). The character who looks like Malfoy is prominently featured in [Ep. 16](https://m.webtoons.com/en/super-hero/the-fever-king/ep-16-archive-2/viewer?title_no=1659&episode_no=16).

Comment: Note: OP said this was the correct answer in a now-deleted answer from another account.